# Select data from two columns as array sorting in one column and grouping in another column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have table like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "points" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "lat" DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    "lon" DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "points" ("id", "lat", "lon") VALUES
    (1,51.11,-0.11),
    (2,51.12,-0.12),
    (3,51.13,-0.13),
    (4,51.14,-0.14),
    (5,52.44,-2.44),
    (6,52.45,-2.45),
    (7,52.46,-2.46),
    (8,52.47,-2.47);
```

How select data from two columns (`lat`, `lon`) as JSON array from table with sorting in one column (`id`)?
The result should be:

```
[
    [51.11,-0.11],[51.12,-0.12],
    [51.13,-0.13],[51.14,-0.14],
    [44,-2.44],[52.45,-2.45],
    [52.46,-2.46],[52.47,-2.47]
]
```

Comment: The desired result does not group. What do you mean by grouping?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I edited question - grouping not need, only sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select to_json(array_agg(array[lat,lon] order by id))
from points
;
                                                      to_json                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [[51.11,-0.11],[51.12,-0.12],[51.13,-0.13],[51.14,-0.14],[52.44,-2.44],[52.45,-2.45],[52.46,-2.46],[52.47,-2.47]]
```